# How to use a sign plus in a PHP variable and get result?

Tags: php

I want to store a plus sign (or any other sign) in a PHP variable and make arithmetic operation.
I tried to store sign plus in variable $c. But PHP it's not accepting it.

```
$a = 3; 
$b = 5;
$с = "+";
```

But when I echo it,

```
echo $a. $c. $b;
```

it gives me the result 35.

I tried  enothoer one way, but it doesn't work:

```
if ($c === "+"){
echo $a + $b;}
else {
echo $a - $b;}
```

The result is -2.
How get result $a + $b?

Comment: Have you tried to check your code for problems? If I execute it, I receive an error, see https://3v4l.org/8SrV1

Comment: ....because you've used an cyrillic `c` in the third line, and a latin `c` in the comparison

Comment: Was just about to say, the two `c` you have are different ASCII codes, hence they are different variables altogether. The one on line 3 is 1089 and the one in your `if` condition is 99 (which is correct).

Comment: @NicoHaase is correct. See working one here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6432701be253715baee3b390a8020e60352355a1

Comment: After seeing the edit: what else did you assume on concatenating three strings?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a combination of the [Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) and latin letter `c` in your code.

If I paste your code on [this site](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) to show each unicode char, the first `c` is an `\u0441` (Cyrillic), how ever, the `c` inside the `if` shows `0x63` (latin), so PHP is unable to match those and trows:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: c

Fixed:

```php
<?php

$a = 3; 
$b = 5;
$c = "+"; 

if ($c === "+"){
echo $a + $b;}
else {
echo $a - $b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyVRwVbB2FqBSyUJyDC15lJJBtJK2kpAIa7MNAUNEN8WLKJZzZWanJGvANSiraCSZF3LlZpTnKqAENUFi/7/DwA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You make my day!